# IIS7 URL Rewrite - RegExp to match any string that does not contain a DOT (.)

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am using URL Rewrite module 2 in IIS 7.

I have a certain rule for rewriting URLs in IIS. But I want that rule to apply to only strings that DO NOT contain a DOT (`.`) If the string contains a DOT, I want it to fail and simply be not rewritten.

I thought `^([^\.]+)` would work but it rejects only strings that start with a DOT.

**Examples:**

`"projects", "about", "contact" should be matched.`

`"script.js", "default.css" should be rejected.`

What is the regular expression I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([^.]+)$
```

Your expression is missing the "$" to match the end of the string, so it is successfully matching 1+ occurrences of a non-DOT character and calling it a day.

Comment: this didn't work at all for me, testing in both RegExr 2.0 and RegExBuddy. you're right about it stopping at the first dot, but your solution to get to the end didn't provide me with results.